# Compile a dataframe from multiple CSVs using list of dfs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a single dataframe from 50 csv files. I need to use only two columns of the csv files namely 'Date' and 'Close'. I tried using the df.join function inside the for loop, but it eats up a lot of memory and i am getting error "Killed:9" after processing of almost 22-23 csv files. 
So, now I am trying to create a list of Dataframes with only 2 columns using the for loop and then I am trying to concat the dfs outside the loop function.

I have following issues to be resolved:-
(i) Though the start date of most of the csv files have start date of 2000-01-01, but there are few csvs which have later start dates. So, I want that the main dataframe should have all the dates, with NaN or empty fields for csv with later start date.
(ii) I want to concat them across the Date as Index.

My code is :-

```
def compileData(symbol):
    with open("nifty50.pickle","rb") as f:
        symbols=pickle.load(f)
    dfList=[]
    main_df=pd.DataFrame()
    for symbol in symbols:
        df=pd.read_csv('/Users/uditvashisht/Documents/udi_py/stocks/stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(symbol),infer_datetime_format=True,usecols=['Date','Close'],index_col=None,header=0)
        df.rename(columns={'Close':symbol}, inplace=True)
        dfList.append(df)
    main_df=pd.concat(dfList,axis=1,ignore_index=True,join='outer')


   print(main_df.head())
```

Comment: I think you can `dflist.append(df.set_index('Date'))` to append each dataframe with the Date set in the index and then when you do the pd.concat with axis=1 it will align on the index.

Comment: I am getting this error "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (50, 4432), indices imply (50, 4428)" on doing that.

Comment: Do known which column your csv is the Date you can use index_col = # then remove the set_index.

Comment: date is at column '0' in csv doing index_col=0 throws the same error.

Comment: It seems your csv files have different columns.  Try running two files first then 5 then 10 files find out where it breaks.

Comment: But, I am extracting only two columns from the csv files that is 'Date' and 'Close'. So I think it shouldn't effect it. Though I guess they have same other columns.

Comment: Yeah... and your process works with out the set index?   Try to just to two files first does that work?  The add files incrementally to see where it breaks and find out what is different about that file that breaks it.

Comment: Found the solution, guess some of the csv file had duplicate entries.
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) helped
thanks for guiding me in the right direction... thanks a lot

Comment: Cool.  Did the set_index work and get your dataframes aligned?

Comment: yup set_index helped in aligning it. though in the code which i run index_col=0 was set. I guess both work in the same way...

Comment: Though I could create a database using the updated code. But I am facing one problem, some of the columns has NaN value in the combined dataframe but if I use read_csv to read the individual csv file corresponding to that csv, it has values in it.

Comment: Hrm...  index alignment?   One thing you might do is to date parse that column on the way in also. Maybe something to do with date format difference, currently I think that are importing as strings, therefore, you could see some nulls for different string formats.  Parsing as dates should help or identify the data causing the problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156611/discussion-between-udit-hari-vashisht-and-scott-boston).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index_col=0` in the read_csv or `dflist.append(df.set_index('Date'))` to put your Date column in the index of each dataframe. Then using pd.concat with axis=1, Pandas will using intrinsic data alignment to align all dataframes based on the index.